# Editable combobox with binding, block missing values

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

There are several similiar questions, but they all seems to be asking for the opposite behavior. I have a data-bound combobox, and I want users to be able to locate values in it by typing, as if it were a textbox. This behavior is easy with IsEditable, but it results in the user being able to select values that are not in the ItemsSource.

When a user does this the Combobox highlights red, but thats it. I want it to actually clear the value out, or select the closest match, whichever is easier. Is this possible without also binding to the text, and putting validation logic in the setter?

Comment: The users actually can find items by typing and marking when combobox as no editable.

Comment: Its much less flexible, and the backspace key functions differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no simple way to solve that problem out of the box.

You'll need to either do as you said, bind to the text, or more correctly (in my opinion at least), make a specialized derived ComboBox/attached behavior where you handle this between PreviewKeyPressed, TextChanged, LostFocus etc.

From personal experience, it can be painful to make custom behaviour like that work perfectly.

I agree that what you'd prefer in a perfect world is the readonly combobox, but with improved "search as you type" where you can actually see what you've typed and edit that on the fly.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid this was the case.